# Validation (HTML 5): Attribute 'txt-id' is not valid attribute of element 'a'

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I got that message when I created a `<a>` tag in .chtml. Could anyone tell me that error and solve it for me? Thanks.

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="RefreshQuantity" data-id="@item.ShoppingCartItemID" txt-id="CartItems_@(ix)__Count" >Refresh quantity</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;

    @Html.ActionLink("Remove from Cart","RemoveCart","ShoppingCart", new {id = item.ShoppingCartItemID},null)

 </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be "valid" change `txt-id` to `data-txt-id`

What you have there isn't a problem so much as it's not "standard" so it won't validate against a formal set of markup rules. In other words... you can leave it if you don't care about seeing green for the sake of seeing green on the validation screen.

Comment: How to resize this button? @d3c0y `<div class="button">@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart",new {id = @bike.ProductID},"")</div>`

Comment: Do you mean how to resize the button via css? I'd have to see the css that applies to the button class. Otherwise `.button { font-size:10px; padding:5px 3px }` is a shot in the dark...

Answer (score 0):

Html5 supports custom attributes as long as if they start with the `data` so change `txt-id to data-txt-id`

## [Html5 Data Attribute](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute--webdesign-9642)